# spamd with postfix: check spam from webmail/localhost

Tags: spamassassin, spamd

I didn't find any way to set postfix with spamd to check outgoing email from webmail/localhost for attempt to ward off possible spam.

Comment: Duplicates is older 7 years.

Comment: Yes. And has answers that still applies.

Comment: Thanks but I'd like use spamd, your suggests is about amavis-new.

Answer (score 0):

The spamassassin daemon is not itself a Postfix content-filter (SMTP proxy), nor a milter for directly processing email content.

If you want to use spamassassin as a content filter, install amavisd-new instead of spamd, and configure Postfix to send whatever mail you want through it and pick up the returning email.  See [www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html).

It's a less common or supported approach, but if you want to use spamd as a milter, look at the [SpamAssassin wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/IntegratedInMta) and choose a wrapper for spamd like MIMEDefang or [milter-spamd](https://www.benzedrine.ch/milter-spamd.html) and look at [www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html).